# eclipse does not show typescript error (angular)

Tags: eclipse, typescript

i am new to angular 4 .
for typescript files -eclipse does not show me any errors in the editor
i see the errors only in the "probelm" tab ( i removed the p from the FormGroup -just for the exalpe )

[see following example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwNDU.png)

[this is the plgin i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa5LH.png)

Comment: As far as I understand this correctly, eclipse does not support syntax error underlines out of the box. So this might be a problem with the corresponding plugin you are using for this.

Comment: if you want to code typescript the best IDE is visual code studio. or you can use eclipse typescript plugin https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/typescript

Comment: but i person that works with me have those errors.. you are saying the problem is with the plugin ? which one ? i have typescript pluging insatll from the market place , i added a screen shot of the plugin i have